# In OS X,every command of pip executing will appear the same Error,what can I do?

Tags: python, macos, pip

The Error is following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
import packaging.requirements
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/packaging/requirements.py", line 59, in <module>
MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR())("marker")
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I tried to install jupyter by using pip,but it was failed.Then I reboot my mac,and executing `csrutil disable` in the terminal.Actually,I dont know what's mean.Finally I find my pip cannot used.I tried to uninstall it,also failed,until the Error which has been posted.

Any help is appreciated,thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back up this `requirements.py` file and modify it:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/packaging/requirements.py
```

Remove the parentheses `MARKER_EXPR`,:

```
#MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR())("marker")
MARKER_EXPR = originalTextFor(MARKER_EXPR)("marker")
```

Or you can upgrade `pip`:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade --force pip
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks you very much,my friend.